# Sandbox test second Payment Failed Paypal Integration asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to integrate Paypal in my .net mvc project. I create an app and add a code in the web.config and in my controller (To see the code see below). **I am able to make a single transaction on a new account But when Ever I called another transaction it returned Transaction failed**: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Here below is my web.config code

```
    <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal" />
  </configSections>
  <!-- PayPal SDK settings -->
  <paypal>
    <settings>
      <add name="mode" value="sandbox" />
      <!--<add name="clientId" value="AfLQXEBebCzqXtXyPYW987x5Zg75PXpTgYACmv8i9pMaWiMCN0U-FIkKPngd3WQ4YK9J-_gE1ZfMiQlb" />
      <add name="clientSecret" value="EFNJZjqrmGkAY-W4-NmCRq-DgkEmCgRteDY_v4aBf6TTU55ZwARMj0399UfFZ5T7iExAtoqq3tdOuyd" />-->
      <add name="clientId" value="AQ3-ATuhAujxd7-Y5BVOKw8fdlIt5KlDul1d0OIJ4hQavS0smxF0Np_MfO6tZXAcuYqklG33yycQnNvj" />
      <add name="clientSecret" value="EA77LpQNkL8U6xH96A2VZTKXjdthToF8yFsw4SKRfGmY5iHMxTv_yxJXMxBHCeXVnNFF_EO5UOeDjq1Q" />
    </settings>
  </paypal>
```

and following are my controller which call paypal api

```
public ActionResult PaymentWithPaypal(string Cancel = null)
    {
        //getting the apiContext  
        APIContext apiContext = PaypalConfiguration.GetAPIContext();
        ////try
        ////{
            //A resource representing a Payer that funds a payment Payment Method as paypal  
            //Payer Id will be returned when payment proceeds or click to pay  
            string payerId = Request.Params["PayerID"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(payerId))
            {
                //this section will be executed first because PayerID doesn't exist  
                //it is returned by the create function call of the payment class  
                // Creating a payment  
                // baseURL is the url on which paypal sendsback the data.  
                string baseURI = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + "/Home/PaymentWithPayPal?";
                //here we are generating guid for storing the paymentID received in session  
                //which will be used in the payment execution  
                var guid = Convert.ToString((new Random()).Next(100000));
                //CreatePayment function gives us the payment approval url  
                //on which payer is redirected for paypal account payment  
                var createdPayment = this.CreatePayment(apiContext, baseURI + "guid=" + guid);
                //get links returned from paypal in response to Create function call  
                var links = createdPayment.links.GetEnumerator();
                string paypalRedirectUrl = null;
                while (links.MoveNext())
                {
                    Links lnk = links.Current;
                    if (lnk.rel.ToLower().Trim().Equals("approval_url"))
                    {
                        //saving the payapalredirect URL to which user will be redirected for payment  
                        paypalRedirectUrl = lnk.href;
                    }
                }
                // saving the paymentID in the key guid  
                Session.Add(guid, createdPayment.id);
                return Redirect(paypalRedirectUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                // This function exectues after receving all parameters for the payment  
                var guid = Request.Params["guid"];
                var executedPayment = ExecutePayment(apiContext, payerId, Session[guid] as string);
                //If executed payment failed then we will show payment failure message to user  
                if (executedPayment.state.ToLower() != "approved")
                {
                    return View("FailureView");
                }
            }
        //}
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View("FailureView");
        }
        //on successful payment, show success page to user.  
        return View("SuccessView");
    }

    private Payment ExecutePayment(APIContext apiContext, string payerId, string paymentId)
    {
        var paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution()
        {
            payer_id = payerId
        };
        this.payment = new Payment()
        {
            id = paymentId
        };
        var a = payment.Execute(apiContext, paymentExecution);
        return a;
    }
    private Payment CreatePayment(APIContext apiContext, string redirectUrl)
    {
        //create itemlist and add item objects to it  
        var itemList = new ItemList()
        {
            items = new List<Item>()
        };
        //Adding Item Details like name, currency, price etc  
        itemList.items.Add(new Item()
        {
            name = "Item Name comes here",
            currency = "USD",
            price = "10",
            quantity = "1",
            sku = "sku"
        });
        var payer = new Payer()
        {
            payment_method = "paypal"
        };
        // Configure Redirect Urls here with RedirectUrls object  
        var redirUrls = new RedirectUrls()
        {
            cancel_url = redirectUrl + "&Cancel=true",
            return_url = redirectUrl
        };
        // Adding Tax, shipping and Subtotal details  
        var details = new Details()
        {
            tax = "1",
            shipping = "1",
            subtotal = "10"
        };
        //Final amount with details  
        var amount = new Amount()
        {
            currency = "USD",
            total = "12", // Total must be equal to sum of tax, shipping and subtotal.  
            details = details
        };
        var transactionList = new List<Transaction>();
        // Adding description about the transaction  
        transactionList.Add(new Transaction()
        {
            description = "Transaction description",
            invoice_number = "your generated invoice number", //Generate an Invoice No  
            amount = amount,
            item_list = itemList
        });
        this.payment = new Payment()
        {
            intent = "sale",
            payer = payer,
            transactions = transactionList,
            redirect_urls = redirUrls
        };
        // Create a payment using a APIContext  
        return this.payment.Create(apiContext);
    }
```

Comment: I hope you will change your paypal `clientSecret` and will not post this type of secret information in future). Oh, it's sandbox...

In addition I see two identical by key `clientSecret` section, it's seem strange.

Comment: I would suggest that you step through your code while debugging. It will tell you what/where the code is failing. Nobody here will do this for you. Hopefully if you know what/where, you can figure what to do, otherwise, come back and revise your question with the specifics of what you debugged. As it stands, it's "too broad". Hth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Below Code to resolve the issue.

```
public Payment CreatePayment(APIContext apiContext, string redirectUrl)
{
    //create itemlist and add item objects to it
    var itemList = new ItemList() { items = new List<Item>() };

    //Adding Item Details like name, currency, price etc
    itemList.items.Add(new Item()
    {
        name = "Item Name comes here",
        currency = "USD",
        price = "4",
        quantity = "1",
        sku = "sku"
    });

    var payer = new Payer() { payment_method = "paypal" };

    // Configure Redirect Urls here with RedirectUrls object
    var redirUrls = new RedirectUrls()
    {
        cancel_url = redirectUrl + "&Cancel=true",
        return_url = redirectUrl
    };

    // Adding Tax, shipping and Subtotal details
    var details = new Details()
    {
        tax = "1",
        shipping = "1",
        subtotal = "4",
        shipping_discount = "-1"
    };

    //Final amount with details
    var amount = new Amount()
    {
        currency = "USD",
        total = "5", // Total must be equal to sum of tax, shipping and subtotal.
        details = details
    };

    var transactionList = new List<Transaction>();
    // Adding description about the transaction
    transactionList.Add(new Transaction()
    {
        description = "Transaction description",
        invoice_number = Convert.ToString((new Random()).Next(100000)), 
        amount = amount,
        item_list = itemList
    });


    this.payment = new Payment()
    {
        intent = "sale",
        payer = payer,
        transactions = transactionList,
        redirect_urls = redirUrls
    };

    // Create a payment using a APIContext
    return this.payment.Create(apiContext);
}
```

Regards
Omkar.